# Best way to ask frequently used infromation?

Tags: usability, forms, gui-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

I have a requirement for a web form (desktop) where user is asked to enter "Three Frequently Dialed Numbers (Last 30 days)". What would be the best way to handle this? Three different input fields or just one field and use comma or space to separate the numbers? Can you come up with any existing examples?

Comment: Will it _always_ be three numbers? Might this change in the future? What happens if the user only has two frequently-dialled numbers? Would the numbers always be entered by the user or might they be selected from elsewhere in your web-app?

Comment: Good questions. Honestly, I don't know. I believe that the user will always enter the numbers manually. It's some kind of a regulatory thing.

Answer (score 2):

I would say definitively multiple fields. Using a form, it should be clear that in every field is just one number. If you use a separator the user has to learn which separator to use. It would be necessary to have an explanation text with the field.

Existing example: contacts on any mobile phone.

Comment: It's also easier to highlight any invalid entries with separate fields.

Comment: Yes, this is what I also learned when experimenting different options. It's also most likely way easier for devs to validate the separate inputs.